# Workaround: Aggregate downstream test results

Tags: jenkins

As far as I know, the feature "Aggregate downstream test results" does not work as expected (and it is very hard to find useful documentation). I'd like to achieve very similar functionality:

Job *Build* triggers jobs *T1*, *T2* in parallel (where *T1* does FindBugs, *T2* does PMD).

**Scenario 1:**
As soon as *T1* and *T2* are finished (which I can achieve using the "Join" plugin) I want to gather the artifacts (*T1*/findbugs.xml and *T2*/pmd.xml). Then these are analyzed and nice statistics are generated.

**Scenario 2 (I like this more):**
Like scenario 1, but the analysis is done as part of *T1* and *T2* (in parallel!). As soon as *T1* and *T2* are finished, the analysis results are combined into nice statistics.

**My questions:**
For scenario 1 I do not know how to reference the downstream projects *T1* and *T2*. I could use the last successful build, but that seems weird when considering many parallel jobs.

For scenario 2 I have no idea how to import the data that is needed for the FindBugs/PMD/Checkstyle/SLOCcount/... plugins so that the corresponding graphs (also?) appear outside of *T1*/*T2*.

Thanks,
Carsten

Comment: I think this question can be generalized to: How can I transfer knowledge from (finished) downstream jobs to its direct upstream job that triggered these jobs (or to a direct successor of this upstream job)? As far as I know, Jenkins focuses on the other direction (getting information from upstream jobs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two additions to malenkiy_scot's post:

1. You don't actually need a script for step 3 in the description: The "copy artifacts from another project" build step allows specifying the source job including parameters already.

   For example, using the parent's notation, it can copy artifacts from the correct execution of job `D` by using `D/PARENT_ID=EXPECTED_VALUE` as the "project name".
2. Instead of manually concatenating `$JOB_NAME` and `$BUILD_ID` you can use the predefined `$BUILD_TAG` (which does essentially the same). See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables for the full list of standard environment variables.

Comment: Is it possible for someone to unpack what is happening here with the syntax 'D/PARENT_ID=EXPECTED_VALUE'? Any help much appreciated. I'd like to hook this up in abstract base builds rather than make them all explicit in the concrete children.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an outline for a somewhat simpler scenario, but I think you can easily generalize it to your case of multiple downstream jobs. The trick is to use "marking" parameters in downstream jobs.

Let *P* be the parent job and *D* be a downstream job.

1. An instance (build) of *P* invokes *D* via [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) via a build step (**not** as a post-build step) and waits for *D*'s to finish. Along with other parameters, *P* passes to *D* a parameter - let's call it *PARENT_ID* - based on *P*'s build's *BUILD_ID*.
2. *D* executes the tests and archives them as artifacts (along with jUnit reports - if applicable).
3. *P* then executes an external Python (or internal Groovy) script that finds the appropriate build of *D* via *PARENT_ID* (you iterate over builds of *D* and examine the value of *PARENT_ID* parameter). The script then copies the artifacts from *D* to *P* and *P* publishes them.

If using Python (that's what I do) - utilize [Python JenkinsAPI wrapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi). If using Groovy - utilize [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) and run your script as system script. You then can access Jenkins via its [Java API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: Thank you, that helped! I now have the data from T1 and T2 in my join project (the one started as soon as T1 and T2 are finished).

Comment: Today I noticed that BUILD_ID is not unique to a job (two jobs started in the same second get the same BUILD_ID). Any idea how to really have unique IDs?

Comment: Concatenate it with *JOB_NAME* (e.g. ${JOB_NAME}_${BUILD_ID})

Answer (score -3):

Jenkins Plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin should help in such requirements.