# Running parallel jobs in Jenkins

Tags: perl, testing, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins for my builds, and I wrote some test scripts that I need to run after the compilation of the build.
I want to save some time, so I have to run the test scripts parallel. How can I do that?

EDIT: ok, I understand know that I need a separate Job for each test (for 4 tests I need 4 jobs, right?)
So, I did that, and via the parent job I ran this jobs. (using "build other projects" plugin).
But I didn't managed to aggregate the results (using aggregate downstream test results). The parent job exits before the downstream jobs were finished. 
What shall I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multi-job plugin. This would allow you to run multiple jobs in parallel and the parent job would wait for the sub jobs to be completed. The parent jobs status can be determined by the sub jobs status.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins doesn't really allow you to run things in parallel. You can however split your build into different jobs to achieve this. It would look like this.

- Job to compile the source runs.
- Jobs that run the tests are triggered by the completion of the compilation and start running. They copy compilation results from the previous job into their workspaces.

This is a big kludgy though. The better alternative would be to parallelise within the scripts that run the tests, i.e. you run a single script and this then runs the tests in parallel. If this is not possible, you'll have to split into different jobs though.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have a little issue, when the build is successful, and only the test fails, Jenkins marks the whole build as "Unstable". If I will split it to two jobs, The build job will be successful, and only the jobs that run the tests will be Unstable. This is a problem for me.
and I have a lot of tests, do I need to create a separate Job for each one?

Comment: You would need separate jobs. Regarding the other issue, you could run a job that collects all the results and gives the right outcome after everything completes.

Comment: but than the first job will still be successful, right? I didn't sure I understand the purpose of the last job..

Comment: Yes, the point of the last job would be that this is the only one you should refer to when determining whether the run was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Jenkins JOIN Plugin? I have not used it but I believe it is what you are attempting to accomplish.

- Mike

Comment: As I wrote above, I need to run some tests in parallel in Jenkins. I can run them one after the other (Not in parallel) by using the "post build actions" in Jenkins under the same project. but I need to run them parallel. I do not want to do it within me perl scripts, I need Jenkins to do it. more clear now? Thanks :)

Comment: Edited my answer to hopefully answer your question.

Comment: The problem with join is that I need to create a join job. I need that the main job will wait for the test results so it can send only one mail with the build rand the tests results..

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051235/workaround-aggregate-downstream-test-results)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can but you will need some coding behind.
In my case, I have parallel test execution on jenkins.

**1)** Create a small job with parameters that is supposed to do a test run with a small suite

**2)** Edit this job to run on a list of slaves (where you have the proper environment)

**3)** Edit this build to allow concurrent builds

And now the hard part.

**4)** Create a small java program for computing the list of parameters for each job to run.

**5)** Iterate trough the list and launch a new Jenkins job on a new thread.

Put a `Thread.sleep(5000)` between runs in order to avoid communication errors

**6)** Join the threads

At the end of each job, I send the results to a shared location in order to perform some reporting at the end of all tests.

For starting a jenkins job with parameters use **CLI**

I intend to make my code as generic as possible and publish it if anyone else will need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin with code like this

parallel (

```
// job 1, 2 and 3 will be scheduled in parallel.
{ build("job1") },
{ build("job2") },
{ build("job3") }
```

)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of the followings:

1. [Multijob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)
2. [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)