# Jenkins executing one job that runs multiple jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

i am new to Jenkins , i need to execute one job that run's another multiple jobs in parallel were it should not stop even if one job fails.

i am not sure how to achieve it. After googling i can achieve by 3 ways Multi-Job plugin , Pipeline multiple Jenkins jobs , Build after other projects , Build Flow Plugin.

can any body please provide me the correct way.

Update : i am trying to achieve this using the pipeline plugin , can any body suggest me were it was correct choice ?..Please suggest!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updated Answer :  i used pipeline plugin to achieve my task and tuffwer was right to if u have paramaterized trigger plugin!..

Answer (score 3):

We use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to do this.

In your build configuration add a Trigger/call builds on other projects build step.  Add the names of the builds you want to trigger as a comma separated list and make sure that the Block until triggered projects finish their builds box is unchecked. Your build will trigger each of the listed builds, however note that your parent build won't wait for them to finish it will just trigger them and then perform the rest of it's buildsteps so if you have buildsteps.

If you do want to wait then check the block until triggered builds finish box, but set the options for when to fail the build, build step or mark the build as unstable appropriately.

If you need to pass parameters to the jobs you can add parameters using this plugin.  If your downstream jobs need different parameters for different jobs you can click the add trigger button which adds another project to build where you can specify different options.

If these other jobs are follow up jobs to the current job and you don't need to wait for them to finish you can also achieve what you want to do by using the post build action build other projects, but again this occurs after the current job and you won't be able to use the results.

> can any body please provide me the correct way.

I wouldn't approach using Jenkins with a "one correct way" mentality.  Often times the requirements of your build will dictate which method or plugin you use in your build configurations.

Comment: i came across this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223658/running-parallel-jobs-in-jenkins , please provide your thoughts, weaather it was good approach or not!..

Comment: @ramki I'm sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, as it stands your question is looking for a way to start multiple downstream jobs from a single parent job.  That's all you've provided.  Are you waiting to collect information from these downstream jobs? Are you just wanting to fire and forget? Exactly what process you need to use really depends on your end goal.  Your linked post looks like it has several solutions that should work insofar as to answer the question you asked, but I've never tried any of them myself so I'm not able to speak to their effectiveness.

Comment: thanks for you response, i am not waiting from any jobs , i just want to fire the parent job which intern triggers multiple jobs and aggregate the status of the parent job based on the child jobs !.. if one child job fails then parent status should also show failed !...

Comment: " If you do want to wait then check the block until triggered builds finish box, but set the options for when to fail the build, build step or mark the build as unstable appropriately" can u please explain this!..

Comment: Once you've added the `Trigger/call builds on other projects` build step to your build there should be a checkbox that says `Block until triggered projects finish their builds`.  Select this and then in the three dropdowns that appear decide if you want the current build job to fail, continue or be marked as unstable based on whether or not the called job fails, succeeds or is unstable.  I can't post a screenshot of the jenkins I'm using.  This method will allow you to gather information about whether the called job succeeded or not, but will not let you do so and run child jobs in parallel.

Comment: it looks like i did not have paramaterized trigger plugin , i cannot see in my maven project configuration at jenkins , Parameterized Trigger Plugin!..i am trying to use pipeline plugin to achieve this!.. can u please suggest your thoughts on this ?.. weather it was best fit or not ?.

Comment: Pipeline is probably the way to go given your requirements, it doesn't sound like the parameterized trigger plugin will do exactly what you want. however I haven't worked with pipeline yet so I'm not sure I would be much help.

Answer (score 2):

The job can start other jobs via the jenkins api.

Comment: you mean from java code ?..i want from Jenkins web interface

Comment: Your job can excecute in the build a code which will call other 2 jobs via the api. This code and be anything that can be excecuted in the bash.