# Aggregating results of downstream is ‘no test’ in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

After running the main project, every downstream project has test result, but the "Latest Aggregated Test Result" is no tests. How to configure the Jenkins to make all the test results display in aggregated list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Workaround: Aggregate downstream test results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051235/workaround-aggregate-downstream-test-results)

Comment: Possible help : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Downstream+buildview+plugin

Answer (score 11):

**Aggregate downstream test results** is not obvious, and not documented.  The steps below are synthesized from [How To Aggregate Downstream Test Results in Hudson](http://shotgunsandpenguins.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-aggregate-downstream-test.html).

To aggregate, you need to archive an artifact in the upstream job, fingerprint the artifact, and then pass the artifact from the upstream job to the downstream job.  In my own words:

> the shared, finger-printed artifact "ties" the jobs together and allows the upstream job to see the downstream test results

To show this, we can make a very simple flow between two free-style jobs, Job_A and Job_B.

**Upstream**

Job_A will run and create an artifact named **some_file.txt**.  We're not aggregating the value/contents of some_file.txt, but it needs to be finger-printed and so it cannot be empty.  Job_A will then trigger a build of Job_B.

*Job_A's configuration*:

1. **Execute shell**:

   ```
   echo $(date) > some_file.txt
   ```
2. **Archive the artifacts**:

   - set **Files to archive** to the file, **some_file.text**
3. **Aggregate downstream test results**:

   - check the **Automatically aggregate...** option
4. **Build other projects**:

   - set **Projects to build** to **Job_B**
5. **Record fingerprints of files to track usage**:

   - set **Files to fingerprint** to **some_file.txt**

**Downstream**

Job_B will run, copy the file some_file.txt from the upstream job that triggered this run, echo out some mock test results to an XML file, then publish that XML result file.  It's the published results that will get aggregated back into Job_A.

*Job_B's configuration*:

1. **Copy artifacts from another project**:

   |  |  |
   | --- | --- |
   | Project name | Job_A |
   | Which build | Upstream build that triggered this job |
   | Artifacts to copy | some_file.txt |
   | Fingerprint Artifacts | ✔ |
2. **Execute shell**:

   ```
   XML_VAR='<testsuite tests="3">
     <testcase classname="foo" name="ASuccessfulTest"/>
     <testcase classname="foo" name="AnotherSuccessfulTest"/>
     <testcase classname="foo" name="AFailingTest">
       <failure type="ValueError">Not enough foo!!</failure>
     </testcase>
   </testsuite>'

   echo $XML_VAR > results.xml
   ```
3. **Publish JUnit test result report**:

   - set **Test report XMLs** with the file, **results.xml**

This should be sufficient to have Job_A aggregate Job_B's test results.  I'm not sure if there's a way/plugin to change Job_A's status based on downstream results (like if Job_B failed, then Job_A would retroactively fail).

Comment: this worked but remember that the 'aggregate' file also needs to be archived, we don't archive anything so I had to explicitly add that

Comment: One gotcha that I figured out the hard way: I was trying to roll up xml test results, so at b's Step 2 (Execute shell: `xml=...`) I was trying to create an empty results.xml file which would then be fingerprinted, i.e. something like `echo. 2>report.xml`. This does NOT work. The file MUST contain something. My solution to that was to do this: `echo ^<testsuites^>^<^/testsuites^ > report.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

**For Scripted Pipeline**,
Say I have:

one upstream job - `mainJob`

two downstream jobs - `downStreamJob1` and `downStreamJob2`.

To aggregate test result from `downstreamJob1` and `downStreamJob2`, here is what the Jenkinsfile will look like:

**downStreamJob1** Jenkinsfile - *Archive and fingerprint the test result xml*

```
archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, 
artifacts: **/test-results/test/*.xml, 
fingerprint: true, defaultExcludes: false
```

**downStreamJob2** Jenkinsfile - *Archive and fingerprint the test result xml*

```
archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, 
artifacts: **/output/junit-report/*.xml,  
fingerprint: true, defaultExcludes: false
```

The `artifacts` path used Fileset to grab all test report XML. Read more about fileset [HERE](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)

**mainJob** Jenkinsfile - *Copy artifact from each of the downstream jobs*

```
copyArtifacts filter: 'build/test-result/test/*.xml', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'downStreamJob1', selector: lastCompleted()

copyArtifacts filter: 'output/junit-report/*.xml', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'downStreamJob2', selector: lastCompleted()
```

The best way to make sure you have the right path for `filter` and `artifacts` is to navigate to the artifact in each downstream job using this url `$BUILD_URL/artifact/` where **BUILD_URL** is Full URL of this build, like http://server:port/jenkins/job/foo/15/