# Aggregate downstream test results doesn't show data

Tags: junit, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Job A (only build) with Job B and Job C which runs the tests. Job B and Job C are triggered as post build action from Job A. File Finger printing and Aggregate down stream results are enabled for Job A.
Job B and C use publish junit test results and finger print.

After the build is complete. Job A's "Last Aggregated Tests" says there are No Tests and also Latest Tests says "no tests".
Last Aggregated Tests link goes to drill down page which lists the Job B and Job C but displays as No tests even though they have tests.

I have tried both automatic aggregation and aggregation for specific jobs. Both results the same.

Please suggest on how to proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregating results of downstream is no test in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808181/aggregating-results-of-downstream-is-no-test-in-jenkins)