# Aggregating test results for multiple upstream jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a parametrized `Jenkins` job that gets executed every time any of the upstream jobs have a stable build; where the number of upstream jobs can vary, but at least there is always one.

(From here on, I will refer to an upstream job as `upstream` and to the downstream job as `downstream`)

Graphically, it's something like this:

```
Upstream_1 ... Upstream_N
  |                   |
  |                   |
  \                   /
   \                 /
    \               / 
     |             |
  Downstream_Parametrized_Job
```

`downstream` executes in a special environment the unit tests for the `upstream` that triggered the execution (all `upstreams` must be tested in this specific environment)

I am able to aggregate the tests results in `upstream` for a specific job, but I'm having a hard time to generalize this for any number of upstream jobs.

For a single job, I've followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27051535/1259884), specifying in `downstream` the name of the `upstream` where to copy the fingerprinted artifact.

[image: Getting the artifact from the upstream]

But this is a problem, since I can have several `upstreams` and I can't specify all the names directly.

Is there a way to tell `Jenkins` to take the artifact from the specific `upstream` that triggered the job, without specifying a name?

So, in the picture, instead of typing `UPSTREAM_1`, would it be possible to use an environment variable, something like `${UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME}`?

([here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project), I don't see any built-in variable like that, but I wouldn't be surprised if it weren't documented)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Copy Artifact Plugin*'s page has a section:

> [**Specifying project dynamically (with variables)**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin#CopyArtifactPlugin-Specifyingprojectdynamically%28withvariables%29)

Define a parameter `UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME` in the downstream and set it accordingly when triggering from the upstream.